# 「baz(() => this);」の「() => this」はどういう意味？

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**下記コードで、

> () => this

はどういう意味でしょうか？**

---

```
  this.a = 0;
  baz(() => this);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[アロー関数](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions)と呼ばれるECMAScript 6で導入された構文で、「引数のない`this`を返す無名関数」を作成しています。

前半の`()`は関数の仮引数宣言です。この場合は`()`ですので引数を取りませんが、一般的には`(a, b, c, ..., z)`のように宣言します。また引数が1個の場合`a =>`のように括弧を省略することが出来ます。

後半の`this`は関数の本体で`{ return this; }`の省略形です。

またアロー関数には「**アロー関数が作成されたときの`this`の値がアロー関数内部で使用される`this`の値になる**」という特徴があります。

仮に質問文のコードを`function`を使って

```
baz(function () { return this });
```

と書き換えると、`baz`内での引数の取り扱いによって関数内の`this`の値が変化してしまいます。

```
function baz(fn) {
    console.log(fn()); // グローバルオブジェクトが出力される

    var obj = { fn: fn };
    console.log(obj.fn()); // objが出力される
}
```

これではなにかと不都合なので、呼び出し側で`this`参照を変数に置き換えたり、

```
var _this = this;
baz(function () { return _this; });
```

関数に渡す引数に`this`となる値を含めて`Function.prototype.call`や`apply`を呼び出して実行するなどの方法がとられていました。

```
baz(this.foo, this);

// function baz(fn, thisArg)
fn.call(thisArg);
```

アロー関数では関数内の`this`はアロー関数式が実行されたときの`this`に束縛されるため、簡潔に匿名関数を定義して他の処理に渡すことが出来ます。

Comment: 「() =>」ってそういう意味なのですね。検索キーワードが分からなかったので助かりました。「アロー関数とthis」については、ざっくり言うと、呼び出し元は全く関係がなく、呼び出される側の 「アロー関数とthis」を囲む実行コンテキストの 値が this へ設定される？ 「アロー関数とthis」を囲む「実行コンテキストがグローバルだったら、thisは常にグローバルオブジェクト」、「実行コンテキストが関数だったらthisは常に関数オブジェクト」を指す、ということでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね。アロー関数内の`this`は「アロー関数のインスタンスを作成した」コンテキストの`this`となります。

Comment: 回答編集ありがとうございました。説明大変分かりやすかったです。参考になりました